# How to compare ISPs speeds in my area?

Tags: internet, speed, isp

Many Internet Speed Test sites logs the obtained info and let you compare speeds between cities. But there is a site that compares speeds between ISPs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

yes, **[DSL reports](http://www.dslreports.com/stest)** also compares ISPs (requires registration)